# TF model wrong output dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, speech-recognition, tensorflow2.0, audio-processing

I am trying to make a model that is able to extract human speech from a recording. To do this I have loaded 1500 noisy files (some of these files are the exact same but with different speech to noise ratios (-1,1,3,5,7). I want my model to take in a wav file as a one  dimensional array/tensor along the horizontal axis, and output a one dimensional array/tensor that I could then play.
currently this is how my data is set up.
[image]

this is how my model is setup
[image]

an error I am having is that I am not able to make a prediction and when I am i get an array/tensor with only one element, instead one with 220500. The reason behind 22050 is that it is the length of the background noise that was overlapped into clean speech so every file is this length.
[image]
I have been messing around with layers.Input because while I want my model to take in every row as one "object"/audio clip. I dont know if that is what's happening because the only "successful" prediction is an error

Answer (score 1):

The model you built expect data in the format (batch_size, 1, 220500), as in the input layer you declared an input_shape of (1, 220500).

For the data you are using you should just use an input_shape of (220500,).

Another problem you might encounter, is that you are using a single unit in the last layer. This way the output of the model will be (batch_size, 1), but you need (batch_size, 220500) as an output.

For this last problem I suggest you to use a generative recurrent neural network.

Comment: appreciate the tip. someone on another forum pointed out to me my issue with the layers (i thought my output would match whatever the structure of my labels). Sadly tho after doing that colab crashes (im assuming due to too many layers) so ill be using your suggestion to find another solution. have a good one